# Mongoose timestamps - Force specific createdAt

Tags: mongoose

I'm using mongoose and mongoose timestamp plugin but i sometimes i want add an object with specific createdAt and not now, it there any way to override timestamp ?

```
var timestamps = require('goodeggs-mongoose-timestamps');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    removed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
});

ClientSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put a createdAt in your schema instead of using plugin?. And you are free to override your createdAt whenever you want.

```
createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
```